# Issues with Processing OpenCV and QuickTime video capture

Tags: java, opencv, processing, quicktime

I'm having difficulty with the Processing OpenCV library:

http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/index.html

I am running the absolute most basic possible sample code:

```
import hypermedia.video.*;

OpenCV opencv;

void setup ()
{
    opencv = new OpenCV( this );
    opencv.capture( width, height );
}

void draw ()
{
    opencv.read();
    background( opencv.image() );
}
```

But every time, I get the console message:

```
SGIdle failed in icvGrabFrame_QT_Cam with error -1
```

and get no video input. My webcam turns on, but the program hangs.

I have seen others online with this problem, however I have not found a single source. I have a feeling it has something to do with QuickTime's video capture, but I'm not sure.

System info:

- Recent MacBook Pro with built-in iSight camera
- OS X 10.7.3 (Lion)
- QuickTime 10.1
- OpenCV 1.1
- Processing 1.5.1

Does anyone know what is going on? It's difficult to get to the actual project when the most basic functionality of the library doesn't work...

Comment: Your sample work for me on os x 10.68… Have you try to read capture without opencv ? or try last alpha processing 2.06a ?

Comment: Have you tried [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) instead?

Answer (score 2):

do a workaround using the video lib and copying the video frames it into openCV layer: http://habu.phpfogapp.com/?p=3

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a workaround using standard library to capture image

```
// OpenCV cannot capture anymore since a iTunes or QuickTime update.
// It returns this error:
// SGIdle failed in icvGrabFrame_QT_Cam with error -1
// This example shows how to use standard video library to capture then
// pass the image to OpenCV.
//
// Pierre Rossel
// 25.2.2013


import hypermedia.video.*;
import processing.video.*;

OpenCV opencv;
Capture video;
int captureW = 640;
int captureH = 480;

void setup ()
{
  size(captureW, captureH);

  opencv = new OpenCV( this );
  opencv.allocate(captureW, captureH);
  opencv.threshold(255); // Clears allocated image

  video = new Capture(this, captureW, captureH);
  video.start();
}

void draw ()
{
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read();
    opencv.copy(video);
  }

  background( opencv.image() );
}
```